# How to populate a serial column based on unique values in another column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to sql and I want to create a new serial column that is populated based on each time a unique value appears in the other column. I have the column lake_id that is not sequential (10,002, 10,005, 10,006, 10,006, 10,008, 10,008, 10,008, 10,008....). I want to populate a new column in the table so it reads (1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4...). See picture below of initial id column. I basically want to reset that column so it starts at 1 but does not lose the unique id of repeating.

Thanks

[image: Lake ID screenshot]

Comment: What you're proposing is not a serial column; it's just a numeric column. Do some reading about `rank()`.

Comment: @Reinderien thanks for pointing me in the right direction.